# SQL Error when trying to JOIN tables

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to run this query:

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM $table 
    LEFT JOIN vacatures ON bedrijven.id = vacatures.id 
    WHERE id = '$id' 
    AND bedrijfID = '$bedrijf_id'");
```

But it fails for some reason. I get this error.

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias
```

When I leave the JOIN part, the query is succesful. Why is this happening?

I'm using PHP & PDO to fetch the queries.

Thanks.

EDIT: I wrote the query thanks of the answers given. This is working:

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM bedrijven 
    LEFT JOIN vacatures v ON bedrijven.id = v.bedrijfID WHERE v.bedrijfID = $bedrijf_id AND v.id = $id");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify one table or the other in `WHERE id = '$id'`, even though they're equal to each other in this case.

You also need to make sure your LEFT JOIN includes `$table`:

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM $table 
  LEFT JOIN vacatures ON $table.id = vacatures.id 
  WHERE $table.id = '$id' 
  AND bedrijfID = '$bedrijf_id'");
```

or:

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM bedrijven 
  LEFT JOIN vacatures ON bedrijven.id = vacatures.id 
  WHERE bedrijven.id = '$id' 
  AND bedrijfID = '$bedrijf_id'");
```

Comment: Updated answer. I'm guessing as to what your variables might be set to, however. It would help if you clarified that in your original question.

Comment: I got it actually working with this query: 
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM bedrijven 
   LEFT JOIN vacatures v ON bedrijven.id = v.bedrijfID WHERE v.bedrijfID = $bedrijf_id AND v.id = $id");

Thanks for the help! 
+1

PS: Late answer due to PC problems...

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't super clear, but if you're just trying to do a simple join where the id on table 1 = id on table 2, then the below statement would work.  If that's what you're attempting to do, then the AND statement is redundant.  Hard to know what you're going for without a clearly defined question with clearly defined variables.  Also, use prepared statements as shown below rather than inserting variables directly into your statement.  And avoid SELECT * whenever possible.  Only select what is absolutely necessary.

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM bedrijven b 
    LEFT JOIN vacatures v 
    ON b.id = v.id
    WHERE v.id = :id");
$query->bindValue(':id', $id);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: I understand it's a bit vague to help, but this also helped my writing the query myself, thanks. +1

Answer (score 0):

The '$id' will be treated as string not as variable.and you need to specify the id as table.id if both of the tables have a field called id.

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM $table LEFT JOIN vacatures ON bedrijven.id =      vacatures.id WHERE $table.id = $id AND bedrijfID = $bedrijf_id");
```